# Trouble to access controls

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am having trouble about access controls from code file in visual studio 2015 like text Box, Label and others.
Previously i can access those controls. I have tried to restart visual studio, but still gave me same result.
Below is the SS.

[image]

Comment: Maybe, there's errors in your file/function (you've deleted/commented out `boxKembali`), or you didn't save it after deleteion/recreation. Try to save it first (Ctrl-S). Then, try to compile. Then look, if the problem exist.

Comment: Ok thank you, problem solved. Save then compile it again :)